# Get rows from all .txt files in directory using python

Tags: python, find

I have some txt files in a directory and I need to get the last 15 lines from all of them. How could I do it using python?

I chose this code:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

dir_path= './'
files = [ f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path,f)) ]
out = []
for file in files:
    filedata = open(join(dir_path, file), "r").readlines()[-15:]
    out.append(filedata)
f = open(r'./fin.txt','w')
f.writelines(out)
f.close()
```

but I get the error "TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings". I think it's because of Russian letters in the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile

for filepath in listdir("/path/to/folder")
    if isfile(filepath): # if need
        last_five_lines = open(filepath).readlines()[-15:]

# or, one line:

x = [open(f).readlines()[-15:] for f in listdir("/path/to/folder") if isfile(f)]
```

**Updated:**

```
lastlines = []
for file in files:
    lastlines += open(join(dir_path, file), "r").readlines()[-15:]
with open('./fin.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lastlines)
```

Comment: Hmm ... Just make sure none of the files are too big and this should work fine.

Comment: This code is good but as I edit in question I have error with writing to file.

Comment: Using `out += filedata` instead of `out.append(filedata)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
import os
from collections import deque

for filename in os.listdir('/some/path'):
    # might want to put a check it's actually a file here...
    # (join it to a root path, or anything else....)
    # and sanity check it's text of a usable kind
    with open(filename) as fin:
        last_15 = deque(fin, 15)
```

`deque` will automatically discard the oldest entry and peak the max size to be 15, so it's an efficient way of keeping just the "last" 'n' items.

Comment: just a matter of style, maybe `with open(filename) as f: last15 = deque(f,15)`

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for edit. That was a bit of a brain burp by me!

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

dir_path= '/usr/lib/something'
files = [ f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path,f)) ]

for file in files:
    filedata = open(join(dir_path, file), "r").readlines()[-15:]
    #do something with the filedata
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
import os

current_dir = os.getcwd()
dir_objects = os.listdir(current_dir)
dict_of_last_15 = {}
for file in dir_objects:
    file_obj = open(file, 'rb')
    content = file_obj.readlines()
    last_15_lines = content[-15:]
    dict_of_last_15[file] = last_15_lines
    print "#############: %s" % file
    print dict_of_last_15[file]
    file_to_check.close()
```